# Есть запрос к базе данных с where условиями где затрагиваются внешние ключи нужно ли мне использовать Laravel relation -и или нет?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть длинный запрос  к базе данных  со сложными where условиями где затрагиваются и  внешние ключи, все работает правильно  но Laravel relation  не использовал.

Как понять когда нужно и можно использовать Laravel отношения ?

Comment: `Laravel relation` используется для упрощения записи (и собсна улучшает понимание кода). На скорость работы влиять не будет, ибо `Eloquent` - это генератор `SQL-запроса`. Грубо говоря он генерирует строку и ее отправляет в СУБД. Внешние ключи затрагиваются в самой СУБД.

Comment: Можно ли утверждать что ,если в `Eloquent` запросе  есть внешние  ключи то обязательно можно использовать  `Laravel relation ` ?

Comment: `обязательно можно использовать` - какая-то несостыковочка. Яж уже сказал - нет. Это сделано для удобства, вы вообще можете в переменную написать запрос в виде строки и отправить его в субд. Работа с внешними ключами и прочее ведется только в субд